# JText Area expands as text is entered

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jscrollbar

Can anyone tell me why a scroll bar will not display in this piece of code ? Instead the text area just keeps expanding as i enter more and more text.

```
JFrame displayframe = new JFrame("All Details");
displayframe.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JTextArea text = new JTextArea(allDetails);
text.setSize(350,200);
text.setEditable(false);

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

displayframe.getContentPane().add(text,scroll);
displayframe.setSize(400, 600);
displayframe.setVisible(true);
```

Thanks, Jessica

Comment: Providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be help you get faster and better help sooner.

Comment: Basically, you never add the scroll pane to the content. Because your adding text, it is removed the scroll pane automatically.try using displayframe.getContentPane().add(text); instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't set the text in the constructor of `JTextArea`, instead, tell it how many rows and columns you want to show. That will restrict it size, which makes the `setSize` line uneeded. Then you can either use `setText` or `append` to add your text. This sample code will do, I think, what you're looking for. Using Reimeus answer to add the `JScrollPane` to the `JFrame`.

```
JFrame displayframe = new JFrame("All Details");
displayframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
displayframe.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JTextArea text = new JTextArea(30,30);
text.setEditable(false);
text.append("22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs\n22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs\n22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs\n22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs22323sfasfs\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline123");

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

displayframe.getContentPane().add(scroll);
displayframe.setSize(400, 600);
displayframe.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: *"tell it how many rows and columns you want to show. That will restrict it size"* - Not really. It will set the preferred size of the component (and may effect the scrollable preferred size but I haven't verified this). Based on the OPs code, it will still expand to fit the text. You are right in that it makes the need for setSize redundant (and should be avoid ;))

Comment: @jonathan Thank you, this fixed the problem. It didnt work for me because I didnt set the col and row size ? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

You're using the `JScrollPane` `scroll` as a constraint for the `add` method. Just add the component directly to the frame

```
displayframe.add(scroll);
```

Comment: them follows advice by Jonathan Drapeau, post an SSCCE

Comment: before anything here to search about word and line wrap

Comment: The `FlowLayout` looks suspicious but without seeing the `SSCCE` any suggestion would be a guess

Comment: @Jessicam93 Using this answer with your code, making the `JTextArea` 100 by 100 and editable, I get scrollbars when needed.

Comment: Its still not working, i made linewrap true but there is no difference.

Comment: @Jessicam93 are you able to reread all advices from comments here about post an SSCCE,

Comment: Remove the statement `displayframe.add(text)`. The `JTextArea` can only have one parent and that is the `JScrollPane` :)

Answer (score 2):

By default, the line wrap property is set to false. You should set it to true. You should a

```
// JTextArea(allDetails, 20, 60); sets rows and columns. instead of setting 
// a size for the text area.
JTextArea text = new JTextArea(allDetails, 20, 60);
text.setEditable(false);

text.setLineWrap(true);
text.setWrapStyleWord(true);  // wrap style if by word instead of chararcter

... 

displayFrame.pack();
```

See [Javadoc for JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29)

You have already put the textArea in the ScrollPane. You only need to add the ScrollPane to the frame.

```
displayframe.add(scroll);
```

See this running example

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTextArea {
    private JScrollPane jsp;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public TestTextArea() {
        String hello = "hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "  
                     + "hello hello hello hello hello hello hello " 
                     + "hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                     + "hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
                     + "hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "; 

        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(hello, 10, 50);
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jsp = new JScrollPane(text);

        frame.add(jsp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new TestTextArea();

            }
        });
    }  
}
```

Comment: JTextArea(int, int); with pack() instead of setSize(int, int);